# Get notified when location permission was changed in native iOS setting

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, location

Can I register my Swift app to an OS notification about location permission change?

For example, let's say that the current state is `denied` and then the user is switching to the settings and change the permission to `always` and then opens my app again. Can I tell that my user had changed the permission and get both the old and the new one or is it too much to ask :) ?

Something like `ABAddressBookRef ntificationaddressbook = ABAddressBookCreate(); ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(ntificationaddressbook, MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback, self);`

Comment: When the user change any of app permission the app will terminate if it open, so after that the app will be launch agin so you can check using if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()

Comment: I wonder who downvoted this question. Is it not legit?

Comment: @A.Munzer i was sure it happened before too but i tried on iOS 13.5.1 and that no longer happens